# How to get functions from a javascript working in c# .aspx file, pointing to the right folder/file with href and src

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, src

I got an .aspx file in which I want to have a file uploader that I got from [here](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). There are examples included how to get this to work. When I test it only do the HTML and javascript I can get it to work, but when I try to get it working with C# I can't get the path to the .js file right.

The example html/javascript file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <style>     
        body {font-size:13px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; width:700px; margin:100px auto;}
    </style>    
</head>    
    <script src="fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>        
        function createUploader(){            
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
                action: 'do-nothing.htm',
                debug: true
            });           
        }

        // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
        // don't wait for the window to load  
        window.onload = createUploader;     
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to get it in the following .aspx file. The .js and .css file are in the D:\svn\Web\Framework\Trunk\test.Web.Framework\Scripts\fileuploader location and the .aspx file is in D:\svn\Web\Healthcare\trunk\test.Web.Healthcare\Areas\Framework\Administration\Entity. I tried to do the following, but this gives me a GET =1325724928825">http://localhost:1304/Administration/blue/en-gb/Entity/Index/~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js?=1325724928825 404 (Not Found) error:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="test.Web.Framework.Core.ViewUserControl<test.Web.Framework.Areas.Administration.Models.NoteModel>" %>
<% using (UI.koform(Model, null))
{ %>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all highlight" data-bind="visible: meta.message">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span><strong data-bind="text: meta.message">
        </strong>
    </div>

    Subject:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:subject" />
    <span data-bind="text: subject"></span>
    <br />
    Text:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:text" />
    <br />
    <!--
    <a href="#" data-bind="click:function(){setvalues() }">set values</a>

-->

    <div class="dialogButtons">
        <button onclick="$('#<%:Model.meta.modelname%>').koform('submit');">
            Save</button>
    </div>


    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link href="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
    </head>
    <div id="file-uploader-demo1">      
        <noscript>          
            <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
            <!-- or put a simple form for upload here -->
        </noscript>         
    </div>

    "~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.css"
    <script src="~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>        
            function createUploader() {
                var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
                    action: 'do-nothing.htm',
                    debug: true
                });
            }

            // in your app create uploader as soon as the DOM is ready
            // don't wait for the window to load  
            window.onload = createUploader;     
        </script>    

<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix.  Replace your hrefs with something like this...

```
<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will resolve the URL relative to your web application's root folder.  Do the same for your stylesheets and other references.

I use this all over the place but particularly in Master Pages.

Comment: great, do you also know how to do this with razor?

Comment: For razor `@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fileuploader/fileuploader.js")`